# Single cycle permutations

Tags: prolog, permutation

Let's take a permutation of numbers {1,2,3,4} which has only one cycle in it. For example it can be: (2,3,4,1). I was wondering, how can I generate all such permutations using Prolog?

I know how to generate all permutations using `select`.

But I can't come up with an idea for how to generate only the one-cycle (i.e. single cycle) permutations.

Could someone give me a small prompt or advice?

Comment: Given n symbols, there are (n-1)! one-cycle permutations of those symbols.  Why?

Comment: read about Stirling numbers of the first kind, which count the number of permutations of n elements with k disjoint cycles. You should see the recurence, and this should help you, or I can explain you

Comment: Please do not remove your question from Stack Overflow. Some people takes time to make good answers, respect their work.

Answer (score 1):

My comment was intended as a hint for producing directly the single cycle permutations, rather than generating all permutations and filtering out the ones that consist of a single cycle.

We should perhaps clarify that two representations of permutations are frequently used.  xyz writes "I know how [to] generate all permutation[s]," presumably meaning something like the code I gave in [this 2006 forum post](http://forum.amzi.com/viewtopic.php?t=688).  Here all permutations are represented according to the way a list rearranges the items in some "standard order" list.

Obviously there are N! permutations of all kinds.  How many of these are single cycle permutations?  That question is easily answered by contemplating the other form useful for permutations, namely as a product of disjoint cycles.  We need to distinguish between a cycle like (1,2,3,4) and the identity permutation [1,2,3,4].  Indeed the cycle (1,2,3,4) maps 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4, and 4 back to 1, so rather than the identity permutation it would be [2,3,4,1] in its list representation.

Now a cycle loops back on itself, so it is arbitrary where we choose to begin the cycle notation.  If we start at 1, for example, then the cycle is determined by the ordering of the following N-1 items.  This shows there are (N-1)! permutations of N things that form a single cycle (necessarily of length N).  Thus we can generate all single cycle permutations in cycle form easily enough, and the problem then reduces to converting from that cycle form to the list form of a permutation.  [Note that in part Mog tackled the conversion going in the other direction: given a permutation as list, ferret out a cycle contained in that permutation (and see if it is full length).]

Here's my code for generating all the one-cycle list permutations of a given "standard order" list, `oneCycle(Identity,Permuted)`:

```
oneCycle([H|T],P) :-
    permute(T,S),
    oneCycle2permute([H|S],[H|T],P).

permute([ ],[ ]) :- !.
permute(L,[H|T]) :-
    omit(H,L,Z),
    permute(Z,T).

omit(H,[H|T],T).
omit(X,[H|T],[H|Z]) :-
    omit(X,T,Z).

oneCycle2permute(_,[ ],[ ]) :- !.
oneCycle2permute(C,[I|Is],[P|Ps]) :-
    mapCycle(C,I,P),
    oneCycle2permute(C,Is,Ps).

mapCycle([X],X,X) :- !.
mapCycle([H|T],X,Y) :-
    mapCycleAux(H,T,X,Y).

mapCycleAux(Y,[X],X,Y) :- !.
mapCycleAux(X,[Y|_],X,Y) :- !.
mapCycleAux(_,[X,Y|_],X,Y) :- !.
mapCycleAux(H,[_|T],X,Y) :-
    mapCycleAux(H,T,X,Y).
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the function for generating all permutations, and filter out the ones that aren't 'one-cycle permutations'?  (Since I'm not at all clear on what 'one-cycle permutations' are, I'm afraid I can't help with writing that filter.)

Answer (score 0):

```
one-cycle([H|T], Permutation) :-
    permutation([H|T], Permutation),
    cycle(H, [H], [H|T], Permutation, Cycle),
    length(Cycle, CycleLength),
    length([H|T], ListLength),
    CycleLength =:= ListLength.
```

The `cycle/5` predicate builds the cycle corresponding to the first argument you pass it. the second argument is an accumulator, initialized to `[FirstArgument]`, the third and fourth one are the original `List` and `Permutation`, the last one is the result (the list containing the elements of the cycle).

```
cycle(Current, Acc, List, Permutation, Cycle) :-
```

The call to `corresponds/4` retrieves the item that took the place of the first argument in the permutation :

```
    corresponds(Current, List, Permutation, R),
```

If this item is in the cycle we're building, it means we're done building the cycle, so we unify `Cycle` and the accumulator (`Acc`).

```
    (   member(R, Acc)
     -> Cycle = Acc
```

If not, we go on by calling recursively our predicate with the corresponding item we found and we add it to the accumulator, so that our building cycle now holds it :

```
     ;  cycle(R, [R|Acc], List, Permutation, Cycle)).

corresponds(N, [N|_], [R|_], R) :-
    !.
corresponds(N, [_|L], [_|P], R) :-
    corresponds(N, L, P, R).
```

Usage :

```
?- one-cycle([1, 2, 3, 4], P).
P = [2, 3, 4, 1] ;
P = [3, 1, 4, 2] ;
P = [3, 4, 2, 1] ;
P = [2, 4, 1, 3] ;
P = [4, 1, 2, 3] ;
P = [4, 3, 1, 2] ;
false.
```

Comment: about cycles and what means one-cycle you can read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: something about the algorithm: we want find one-cycle permutation. So we have two lists L and P. P is the permutation of L with only one cycle. So, first we check if true: permutation(L,P). Then we can see, that head of L and head of P shoudn't be the same number. Next, let's take [1,2,3,4] and [4,1,2,3], so we see that if we choose head from L and from P we notice that 2,3,4 can't be the permutation of [1,2,3] (because of the definition of one cycle).

Comment: I added what I think is a correct solution, since now I understood what cycles are (at last :( )

Comment: I just basically build one cycle, and if this cycle isn't of the size of the list then the permutation isn't a one-cycle one. What do you think of it ?

Comment: it builts a cycle so that we can compare its length to the list, because if the permutation is a one-cycle permutation, any of its cycle (it's only one even) has the same length as the list...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the discussion in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9199581/849891) by [hardmath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487781/hardmath) I was able to understand what it was all about.

It seems the solution is quite simply to replace the input list's tail with its permutation to form a *cycle description*, then transform *that* into its *list representation* by paring up each element with its next and sorting on the first component to get the list of the second components as the result list:

```erlang
single_cycled_permutation([A|B],   R) :-
  permutation(B,    P),
  cycle_pairs(A, A, P, CP),
  sort(                CP, SCP),
  maplist( pair,           SCP, _, R).

pair( X-Y, X, Y).

cycle_pairs(  A, X, [Y|Z], [X-Y|W]) :-
  cycle_pairs(A, Y,    Z ,      W ).
cycle_pairs(  A, X, [   ], [X-A]  ).
```

To easier see the cycles simply remove the last goal in `single_cycled_permutation`:

```erlang
single_cycled_pairs([A|B], SCP) :-
  permutation(B,    P),
  cycle_pairs(A, A, P, CP),
  sort(                CP, SCP).
```

Testing:

> ```erlang
> 21 ?- forall(  single_cycled_pairs([1,2,3,4], SCP), 
>                (maplist(pair,SCP,_,R), write((SCP,R)), nl)).
> [1-2,2-3,3-4,4-1],[2,3,4,1]
> [1-2,2-4,3-1,4-3],[2,4,1,3]
> [1-3,2-4,3-2,4-1],[3,4,2,1]
> [1-3,2-1,3-4,4-2],[3,1,4,2]
> [1-4,2-3,3-1,4-2],[4,3,1,2]
> [1-4,2-1,3-2,4-3],[4,1,2,3]
> true.
> ```

See also:

- [Cyclic permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation)
- [Cycles and fixed points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycles_and_fixed_points)